# InvalidOperationException for executing LINQ query

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, exception

```
'Initialize The Database Connection'

Dim dbTRCoreDatabase As New TRCoreDatabase

'Query For Get The Employee ID'
Dim listEmployeeID As IQueryable(Of Long) = (From EmpMaster In dbTRCoreDatabase.EmployeeMasters Where EmpMaster.Email = Session("gUserName") Select EmpMaster.EmployeeID)

MsgBox(listEmployeeID(0).ToString)
```

When i execute this query,I have the following Error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occured during the
>   execution of '
>   `Extent<TR_Portal_Homecare.EmployeeMaster>.Where(EmpMaster =>
>   Convert(CompareObjectEqual(Convert(EmpMaster.Email),
>   value(ASP.activeplacement_aspx).Session.get_Item("gUserName"),
>   False))).Select(EmpMaster => EmpMaster.EmployeeID)`'. See
>   InnerException for more details.  ---> System.InvalidCastException:
>   Unable to cast object of type
>   '`Telerik.OpenAccess.Query.MethodCallTransformation`' to type
>   '`OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.query.Node`'.    at
>   Telerik.OpenAccess.Query.ExpressionCompiler.PerformDatabaseQueryImpl(Type
>   type, Int32 elementAt, Object[] groupResolutionParamValues, Boolean
>   single)    at
>   Telerik.OpenAccess.Query.ExpressionCompiler.PerformDatabaseQuery(Type
>   type, Int32 elementAt, Object[] groupResolutionParamValues, Boolean
>   single)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Telerik.OpenAccess.Query.ExpressionCompiler.PerformDatabaseQuery(Type
>   type, Int32 elementAt, Object[] groupResolutionParamValues, Boolean
>   single)    at
>   Telerik.OpenAccess.Query.ExpressionExecution.PerformDatabaseQuerySingle[TResult,T](Piece`1
>   piece, Int32& found, Int32 elemAt, Boolean single)    at
>   Telerik.OpenAccess.Query.ExpressionExecution.PerformQuerySingle[T,TResult](Piece`1
>   piece, Expression expression)    at
>   Telerik.OpenAccess.Query.Piece`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expr)    at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.ElementAtOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source,
>   Int32 index)    at TR_Portal_Homecare.ActivePlacement.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   E:\Palanikumar\Project\Today\TRCorePortal\TR_Portal_Homecare\ActivePlacement.aspx.vb:line
>   12

Answer (score 0):

I think, the error is in your where clause. Check if types of `EmpMaster.Email` and `Session("gUserName")` are same. I believe they are not.

Comment: Thanks Sir.But the session("gUsertName") return the string value of Email Id.If i store the value of Session("gUserName") in String variable and then i assign to the Linq query it will be work but assign the direct session object it will throw the exception.Sorry for my English.

Comment: The error that pointed me towards it is `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.OpenAccess.Query.MethodCallTransformation' to type 'OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.query.Node'`

Comment: I am not familiar with telerik extensions, but what does `dbTRCoreDatabase.EmployeeMasters` return? Is it an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: dbTRCoreDatabase is the object of Telerik Open Access.dbTRCoreDatabase.EmployeeMasters return the Table as object.

Comment: I believe `dbTRCoreDatabase.EmployeeMasters` is not returning IEnumerable/IQueryable, not very sure though. Could you try `dbTRCoreDatabase.EmployeeMasters.AsEnumerable()` in your query?